# Expressjs with Connect basic auth won't set request user

Tags: node.js, express, connect, basic-authentication

I'm using express and adding in basic authentication via the connect middleware. I'm trying to use the async version and it claims the `user` property will be set on the request object when calling using the async version.

If I call the proper `fn(err, obj);` with an object then the basic authentication passes and moves onto my routes, but I want to have the `req.user` set when it gets to my route.

[Here](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/basicAuth.html) is the connect doc on basic auth.

Am I not calling the callback properly?

```
app.use(express.basicAuth(function(user, pass, fn){

    db.getUserByEmail(user, function(err, obj){

      if (err) sendError(500, req, 'error', err);
      else if (obj == null) fn(err, obj); 
      else if (obj.password == pass) fn(null, obj); 
      else fn(null, null); 

    });
  }));
```

Comment: Not a solution, but have you seen [passportjs](http://passportjs.com)? A very well documented authentication framework with all necessary strategies.

Comment: Thanks, I like the look of passport. Funny though, passport is just a skin on Connect, and [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate.html) is my issue where it is setting req.user. Maybe it will work having it go through passport? I'll try.

Comment: it works, and having documentation was nice. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked code in docs, you've attached, it already set up req.user, so, everything should work fine if this is exactly the same code executed as in docs :)

BTW, why not use something more friendly, and well-documented like passportjs?

Comment: Thanks, things seem to work when I use passport, even though it's basically connect with a skin on it. The documentation makes all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike mentioned in the documentation for **connect**, in **express** the authenticated user will be assigned to `req.remoteUser`